# Select query with multiple joins

Tags: join

I have the following tables:

```
ORDERS:  OrderID(VARCHAR), CreatedDate(DATETIME), QuoteID(INT), BasketID(INT)
BASKETS: BasketID(NUMBER), ItemID(NUMBER)
ITEMS:   ItemID(NUMBER), QuoteID (NUMBER), ParcelID(NUMBER)
PARCELS: ParcelID(NUMBER), OrderID (VARCHAR)
QUOTE:   QuoteID(NUMBER), Price(NUMBER), Tax(NUMBER), Shipping(NUMBER)
```

I need to write a query that returns the shipping and tax price per item per parcel for a given order id.

I suck at SQL so I just need to have an example to understand completely on how to concatenate multiple tables.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! With questions such as these, could you please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with, at the very least, your table structures. **Even** better would be some sample data and a desired result. Varing your sample data and result wouid be a good way to learn about joins. If you haven't chosen a particular RDBMS, I'd like to recomment PostgreSQL (personal choice) - it's F/LOSS and very standards compliant!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an obtuse question but, if you are unfamiliar to SQL queries, is it "safe" for you to be writing code that concerns money? Customers really dislike it when numbers are wrong, accountants will shout and scream, and governments hate it even more ...

That said, to join on multiple tables, you would *generally* use multiple join statements. Something like:

```
SELECT {Column A}, {Column B}, {Column C}, ...
  FROM {Table A} INNER JOIN {Table B} ON {Table A}.{Key} = {Table B}.{Key}
                 INNER JOIN {Table C} ON {Table B}.{Key} = {Table C}.{Key}
                 ...
 WHERE {Column X} = {id}
```

<sub>**Note:** Be sure to replace the items wrapped in `{}` with proper column and table names. Do not include the `{` or `}` characters.</sub>

This can be slightly different depending on which database engine you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

To answer your question: it is not for work, production data, or stuff like that. 
It's just for learning and this question popped into my head, because I can't seem to understand how these joins work for multiple tables (I was able to get information from two tables, but I get stumbled when there are more requests involved. 

I do understand a simple join, but I would want to emulate a "work-like" request to get the stuff I want. 

So, this is only for learning purposes and not work.